# What does it mean to say an independent contractor may terminate a contract "for convenience"?

Tags: quitting, independent-contractor

I'm nearing month three of a six month assignment, and would like to terminate it to move on to a better opportunity.

My contract states the following:

> The Independent Contractor may terminate these terms **for convenience** by giving no less than 14 calendar days' notice in writing to the Client and {Recruiter}.

What does "for convenience" mean? Am I allowed to terminate the contract without legal repercussions (assuming I haven't maliciously, or through negligence, caused harm to the company)?

It's a UK company, and I was recruited by a UK staffing firm, but I live in the US and my office is in NYC.

Comment: Contracts (and legal stuff in general) varies widely from location to location. At the minimum, you should indicate what country you're working in.

Comment: Actually; it's kind of interesting.  It's UK company, and I was recruited by a UK staffing firm, but I live in the US and my office is in NYC.  Not sure how much that muddies the waters.

Answer (score 6):

> Am I interpreting the clause properly?

Yes.

Give at least than 14 calendar days written notice to both the Client and the Recruiter. Work out those 14 days. Then you are free.